# Неизвестный инициализатор: GlorotUniform

Tags: python

Пытаюсь загрузить модель 'defects_model.json' с весами 'defects_weight.h5' и распечатать информацию по ней.
Выводит ошибку: "ValueError: Unknown initializer: GlorotUniform"
Не могу понять, в чем может быть причина.

```
import keras
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.models import model_from_json
from keras.utils import CustomObjectScope
from keras.initializers import glorot_uniform

# Загружаем данные об архитектуре сети из файла json
json_file = open('defects_model.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
# Создаем модель на основе загруженных данных
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
# Загружаем веса в модель
loaded_model.load_weights('defects_weight.h5')
loaded_model.summary()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53183865/unknown-initializer-glorotuniform-when-loading-keras-model

Comment: Все то же самое...

Comment: Такой же результат выдают приемы опубликованные по ссылке. Либо я что-то не так делаю.